# Moving Data from SQL Server to Oracle Repeatedly

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

What are the most reasonable ways to move table data from SQL Server to Oracle (on *nix) on a regular basis?

Answer (score 10):

Using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is likely your best bet.  If you're not familiar with SSIS, the best way to try something out is to use the SQL Server Export Wizard and have it create an SSIS package for you.  For example, if you go into SQL Server Management Studio and right-click on your database, then select Tasks->Export Data.  From there click next until you get to the "Choose a Destination" step.  Select the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" and click Properties to define your database connection.  When you click through the wizard, on the Save and Execute page, make sure you check the checkbox labelled "Save SSIS Package", on the next screen specify where to save the SSIS package.  Once you finish the Export Wizard, your data will have been exported and you will have an SSIS package that you can use as is, or go in and tweak it to do more specific things.
Once you have your SSIS package, you can schedule it by creating a SQL Server Agent Job.

Answer (score 7):

- Oracle [Heterogeneous Connectivity](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/toc.htm) / [Database Gateways](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/gateways/index.html) in conjunction with materialized view(s), PL/SQL, or Java
- [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) or [DTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services): both can be scheduled but require more than read-only access to SQL Server
- Java (probably within Oracle but optionally at the OS) using ODBC or SQLJ to access SQL Server and, possibly, Oracle
- SQL Server scheduled to export to CSV, Oracle scheduled to import from CSV
- Any of the other ETL tools (e.g. Informatica, Cognos)
- Any of the myriad languages that can access both databases (but would require maintaining a third environment to run the application within)

Scheduling:

- Automatic / not reuqired with materialized views
- Oracle DBMS_JOB / DBMS_SCHEDULER
- OS-specific (cron, Windows Scheduled Tasks, etc)
- In the case of SSIS, DTS, or CSV export, scheduled within SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

Create a database link from Oracle to Sql Server (heterogeneous connectivity). You can use this link to retrieve the data from Sql Server with a simple select statement. If you want to schedule you can use a materialized view or dbms_scheduler.

An alternative is to put your data in a csv file, you can use an external table or sqlloader to load this data in the Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't actually heard the term "Heterogeneous Connectivity" before. It sounds (in 10g, at least) that it encompasses both Transparent Gateways and Generic Connectivity Agents (ODBC, OLE DB).

Comment: While reading the official admin guide and seeing another mention of using materialized views, it sunk in how brilliant that solution (heterogeneous connectivity + materialized views) could be. +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I do:
Connect to SQL Server by Oracle SQL developer using this link: 
https://kentgraziano.com/2013/01/14/tech-tip-connect-to-sql-server-using-oracle-sql-developer/

After you have added SQL jar, you will see SQL Server tab in the Connection window:

[image]

Then connect to the SQL Instance.

Then open SQL instance and choose database or table that you want to copy. Right click on any database/table, then click on "copy to oracle" there and choose the right user[database] at "Destination Connection Name " where you want to copy your tables.

You can also change some properties there.
Click "OK" and that's it.

Let me know in case of any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can have SQL Server interface with Oracle directly through SSIS (or DTS for 2k).  It will provide ETL functionality and can be scheduled on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

I had success creating a linked server (from within the Enterprise Manager, I think) to Oracle on the SQL Server side.  Then I could use normal stored procedures on both sides to accomplish smaller data movement and updates in both directions.  This approach can bypass the need to try and put something together outside the databases.

Try hard to use the latest possible Oracle client on the SQL Server side though.  I recall some defects in the 10.2.0.2 client and getting the 10.2.0.4 client required your "official" Oracle registration or purchase number or something.

For big data moves (or maybe even moves/updates you want done on a daily or less frequent basis), definitely use one of the ETL tools.  We had Informatica for our ETL processes, but if SSIS can pull off what you need, that's fine too.

Comment: You mean SQL Server's Enterprise Manager, not Oracle's, right?

Comment: Yes, it was on the SQL Server side.  I don't have the specifics in front of me, but it took a little Googling to figure out the exact process.