# Copy database table from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving Data from SQL Server to Oracle Repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571051/moving-data-from-sql-server-to-oracle-repeatedly)

Is it possible to copy a table from SQL Server to a new table in Oracle?

I am pretty sure that it is not possible, but I would like an expert confirmation and how if it exists.

```
CREATE TABLE `backup_db.backup_table` 
  SELECT * FROM `live_db.live_table`;
```

**EDIT**

To be more clear, I need to copy this table every day from SQL Server to Oracle.

I know that it is not elegant, but I have no other choice.

Comment: No, it does not exist.  The migration tool is the right answer.  Your design is flawed.

Comment: I know that, but I must live with these two databases. Thanks for your comment

Comment: It makes sense if MS SQL Server is a transactional database and Oracle is for data mining and reporting.  But in any case you need an ETL tool.   There is no simple way to do it like your example.

Comment: If you need to push that data from SQL Server to Oracle every day, check out the SQL Server **replication** features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Use MS SSIS and transfer data from SQL Server to Oracle using SSIS package and its scheduled execution (MS SQL Server Agent).
2. Use Oracle Transparent Gateway for MS SQL Server and don't physically pull data from MS SQL Server, but rather select it from MS SQL every time you need it in Oracle. Or, do Oracle insert once per day to transfer data from MS SQL to Oracle still using transparent gateway and linked MS SQL Server:

   TRUNCATE TABLE OracleTable
   INSERT INTO OracleTable SELECT * FROM SQLServerTable@SQLServer
   COMMIT

Comment: Great, I will try your solution next days

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you might want to consider setting up a SQL Server Agent job to dump the table to a flat file which is then accessible on a file system to Oracle. Oracle could then access this as an external table.

Comment: Yes, it is a good workaround, I will consider this possibility